# Efficient way of reading only first row of a table as a vector

Tags: r

I have a .csv files with many rows. However, I want to read only the first row in a vector format. I know that this works:

```
names(read.csv("file.csv",nrows=1L))
```

However it creates a data.frame first before reading the names which seems very inefficient. Weirdly, this doesn't seem to work:

```
names(read.csv("file.csv",nrows=0L))
```

I also tried using `strsplit(readLines())`, but the row contains quotes which are read as backslash and so this method doesn't work.

I have also tried using fread, but it is as slow as read.csv.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? For reference, here's what the first row looks like:

`"Timestamp","Parameter_1","Parameter_2","Parameter_3"`

Comment: Have you tried `scan`?

Comment: Nope, it seems very sensitive to the arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
con <- file("somefile.csv")
st <- scan(con, what = "", nlines = 1, sep=",", quote = "\"",)
```

class(st): returns a character vector